# What are differences between digitalized versions of Sabon typeface by different foundries?

Tags: fonts, typography

Linotype, Monotype, Adobe... There are many versions of Sabon available for choice. What are differences, and then is there any one better than others?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The differences are usually very minor ones and sometimes very hard to notice. It can be a slightly different kerning for example.

None are better than the other. **The important thing is to try to stick to the same version when possible.** Otherwise your publishing or design software might not recognize the version you're using and will show the font as missing... and then you would need to replace it with the new Sabon version or switch back to the other Sabon you originally used!

The other problem that may happen from not using the same one is that if your software recognizes it, you might need to verify your texts again, especially paragraphs with a lot of text; if the kerning is slightly different, you might find hyphenations where there wasn't or the text could move a bit, for example.

To avoid that kind of issues, I always create a "fonts" folder in my project's folder, and save my project's fonts in it. Then open them using a font management software (ex. Extensis Suicase/Fusion) when I need to work on the project. That works well for me because I use Postscripts and TrueType fonts.